# Python: Unable to expand a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I extract information from a website and able to get the data. however, I unable to expend the data for 'K" but successfully for 'J' and ''L' .

```
print "hello from python 2"
from lxml import html
import requests
import csv
import pandas as pd
import MySQLdb as mdb
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

bursa = ['J','K','L']
bursalist = []
print bursalist
for x in range (len(bursa)):
    try:
        page = requests.get('https://www.malaysiastock.biz/Listed-Companies.aspx?type=A&value='+bursa[x])

        tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
        tree1 = tree.xpath('//td/h3/a[contains(text(),"(")][not(contains(text(),"(F"))]/text()')
        tree2 = tree.xpath('.//td/h3/text()')
        len(tree1)
        alist = []
        for y in range (len(tree1)):
            a = tree1[y].split('(')
            b = a[1].split(')')
            alist.append(a[0])
            alist.append(b[0])
            alist.append(tree2[2*y])
            alist.append(tree2[2*y+1])

            a = alist

        bursalist.extend(alist)

        print bursalist
    except Exception:
        print "no data"
```

Notice that print bursalist only show data from 'J' and 'L' while 'K' is missing. But if I get the data from alist, data'K' is shown but unable to extend.
please advise if there is a robust way to do it

print alist will show

```
['K1 ', '0111', 'K-ONE TECHNOLOGY BERHAD', 'Technology Equipment ', 'KAB ', '0193', 'KEJURUTERAAN ASASTERA BERHAD', 'Industrial Engineering ', 'KAMDAR ', '8672', 'KA
MDAR GROUP (M) BERHAD', 'Retailers ', 'KANGER ', '0170', 'KANGER INTERNATIONAL BERHAD', 'Household Goods ', 'KAREX ', '5247', 'KAREX BERHAD', 'Personal Goods ', 'KAR
YON ', '0054', 'KARYON INDUSTRIES BERHAD', 'Chemicals ', 'KAWAN ', '7216', 'KAWAN FOOD BERHAD', 'Food & Beverages ', 'KEINHIN ', '7199', 'KEIN HING INTERNATIONAL BER
HAD', 'Metals ', 'KEN ', '7323', 'KEN HOLDINGS BERHAD', 'Property ', 'KENANGA ', '6483', 'KENANGA INVESTMENT BANK BERHAD', 'Other Financials ', 'KERJAYA ', '7161', '
KERJAYA PROSPEK GROUP BERHAD', 'Construction ', 'KESM ', '9334', 'KESM INDUSTRIES BERHAD', 'Semiconductors ', 'KEYASIC ', '0143', 'KEY ASIC BERHAD', 'Semiconductors 
', 'KFIMA ', '6491', 'KUMPULAN FIMA BERHAD', 'Diversified Industrials ', 'KGB ', '0151', 'KELINGTON GROUP BERHAD', 'Industrial Engineering ', 'KGROUP ', '0036', 'KEY
 ALLIANCE GROUP BERHAD', 'Technology Equipment ', 'KHEESAN ', '6203', 'KHEE SAN BERHAD', 'Food & Beverages ', 'KHIND ', '7062', 'KHIND HOLDINGS BERHAD', 'Household G
oods ', 'KHJB ', '0210', 'KIM HIN JOO (MALAYSIA) BERHAD', 'Retailers ', 'KIALIM ', '6211', 'KIA LIM BERHAD', 'Building Materials ', 'KIMHIN ', '5371', 'KIM HIN INDUS
TRY BERHAD', 'Building Materials ', 'KIMLUN ', '5171', 'KIMLUN CORPORATION BERHAD', 'Construction ', 'KINSTEL ', '5060', 'KINSTEEL BHD', 'Metals ', 'KIPREIT ', '5280
', 'KIP REAL ESTATE INVESTMENT TRUST', 'Real Estate Investment Trusts ', 'KKB ', '9466', 'KKB ENGINEERING BERHAD', 'Industrial Engineering ', 'KLCC ', '5235SS', 'KLC
C PROPERTY HOLDINGS BERHAD', 'Real Estate Investment Trusts ', 'KLCI1XI ', '0835EA', 'KENANGA KLCI DAILY (-1X) INVERSE ETF', 'KENANGA KLCI DAILY 2X LEVERAGED ETF', '
NUSFOR ', '5035', 'KOBAY TECHNOLOGY BERHAD', 'Industrial Materials, Components & Equipment ', 'KOBAY ', '6971', 'KOMARKCORP BERHAD', 'Packaging Materials ', 'KOMARK 
KLCI2XL ', '0834EA', 'KUALA LUMPUR KEPONG BERHAD', 'Plantation ', 'KLK ', '2445', 'KLUANG RUBBER COMPANY (MALAYA) BERHAD', 'Plantation ', 'KLUANG ', '2453', 'KIM LOONG RESOURCES BERHAD', 'Plantation ', 'KMLOONG ', '5027', 'KNM GROUP BERHAD', 'Other Energy Resources ', 'KNM ', '7164', 'KNUSFORD BERHAD', 'Industrial Services ', 'KNUSFOR ', '5035', 'KOBAY TECHNOLOGY BERHAD', 'Industrial Materials, Components & Equipment ', 'KOBAY ', '6971', 'KOMARKCORP BERHAD', 'Packaging Materials ', 'KOMARK ', '7017', 'KOSSAN RUBBER INDUSTRIES BERHAD', 'Health Care Equipment & Services ', 'KOSSAN ', '7153', 'KOTRA INDUSTRIES BERHAD', 'Pharmaceuticals ', 'KOTRA ', '0002', 'KPJ HEALTHCARE BERHAD', 'Health Care Providers ', 'KPJ ', '5878', 'KUMPULAN POWERNET BERHAD', 'Personal Goods ', 'KPOWER ', '7130', 'KERJAYA PROSPEK PROPERTY BERHAD', 'Property ', 'KPPROP ', '7077', 'KUMPULAN PERANGSANG SELANGOR BERHAD', 'Diversified Industrials ', 'KPS ', '5843', 'KPS CONSORTIUM BERHAD', 'Wood & Wood Products ', 'KPSCB ', '9121', 'KRETAM HOLDINGS BERHAD', 'Plantation ', 'KRETAM ', '1996', 'KRONOLOGI ASIA BERHAD', 'Digital Services ', 'KRONO ', '0176', 'KECK SENG (MALAYSIA) BERHAD', 'Diversified Industrials ', 'KSENG ', '3476', 'KSL HOLDINGS BERHAD', 'Property ', 'KSL ', '5038', 'K.SENG SENG CORPORATION BERHAD', 'Industrial Materials, Components & Equipment ', 'KSSC ', '5192', 'K-STAR SPORTS LIMITED', 'Personal Goods ', 'KSTAR ', '5172', 'KONSORTIUM TRANSNASIONAL BERHAD', 'Travel, Leisure & Hospitality ', 'KTB ', '4847', 'KIM TECK CHEONG CONSOLIDATED BERHAD', 'Consumer Services ', 'KTC ', '0180', 'KUB MALAYSIA BERHAD', 'Industrial Services ', 'KUB ', '6874', 'KUCHAI DEVELOPMENT BERHAD', 'Other Financials ', 'KUCHAI ', '2186', 'KWANTAS CORPORATION BERHAD', 'Plantation ', 'KWANTAS ', '6572', 'KYM HOLDINGS BERHAD', 'Pack
aging Materials ', 'KYM ', '8362']
```

Comment: Why do you do `for x in range(len(bursa))` instead of the simpler `for x in bursa`?

Comment: What's the point of `a = alist`? You reassign `a` immediately on the next iteration.

Comment: @Barmar. 'for x in bursa' is simpler but the outcome still the same.

Comment: I never said the output would be different, it was an unrelated comment.

Comment: Are you sure there's anything in `tree1` for `K`? Add `print(len(tree1))`

Comment: @Barmar yes. it can be eliminated too. Thanks

Comment: @Barmer, yes...there are element in tree1. It works fine until 'alist '

Comment: Add more print statements so you can see what's happening at every step.

Comment: I able to know for 'K' , the problem started from 'bursalist.extend(alist)' but unable to figure out what is wrong. Add the list for 'K'

Comment: Why are you doing `except Exception: continue`?

Comment: @AMC sorry, amended to a print